# Python __init__.py not turning main directory into a package

Tags: python, import, package

I'm sorry, I'm sure this question has been asked very often, but for the life of me I cannot get past this, and the links I have found don't seem to work.

My file structure looks like this

```
soar/
  __init__.py
  SignIn.py
  SignInOTP.py
  90min/
      __init__.py
      main.py
```

In my main.py, I am trying to access methods within SignIn and SignInOTP. I have tried multiple ways to access these, with no luck.

```
from ..SignIn import sign_in
from ..SignInOTP import sign_in_otp
```

To my knowledge, since I have the `__init__.py` files in both directories, they are both packages. Yet that does not seem to be the case according to pycharm, as the soar directory does not have the package icon to it.

My init files are all blank, as i think I dont need anything from them. The error I am getting is

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

When I try and run the file via `python -m '.\90min\main.py'`, I get this:

```
C:\Users\path\to\python.exe: Relative module names not supported
```

This is a common error, I know, but for the life of me I cannot figure it out. I know it will likely be a small fix, but I dont quite understand how python imports work fully. I know I can work around this by moving the SignIn and SignInOTP files to the 90min directory, but my Java brain wants those 2 files to be in the main soar directory since those 2 files will be used in other directories, not just the 90min one.

Comment: `90min` is not a valid Python name.

Answer (score 1):

from outside `soar`, use `python -m soar.90min.main`.

You need to utilize `soar` as the main package, and the main file as a file within it.

Relative imports will then work correctly.

Keep in mind in most style guides relative imports are discouraged.

Comment: So is it really best practices to duplicate files in this case? Or is it better to just have all files in the same directory to not have to deal with relative imports

Comment: No and no. Best advice is to use absolute imports.

Comment: And as noted, change 90min to min90, Python identifiers should not start with a number